# Tinymce - chenges code inside anchor tag - what are configration settings

Tags: html, css, tinymce

I have following piece of HTML

```
<a href="#" class="list-feature__link"><img class="left" src="images/list/sell_off.svg" />
<div class="list-feature__text">
<h4>Sell your design</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amen lorem</p>                                     </div>
</a>
```

Tinymce changes it to :

```
<a href="#" class="list-feature__link"><img class="left" src="images/list/sell_off.svg" /></a>
<div class="list-feature__text">
<h4>Sell your design</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amen lorem</p>
</div>
```

what are the correct configration setting for tinymce to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following property into you TinyMce Configration

```
valid_children:"+a[elements to allow inside a]",
valid_children:"+a[div|i|span|img|p|ul|ol|li|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h5|h6]",
```