# Tinymce not editing anchor tag correctly

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I am using Tinymce in my application for editing templates.In my template i have some anchor tags like -

```
<div style="font-size:11px; line-height:13px; font-weight:normal;">
<a href="www.somelink.com">Some text here</a>
</div>
```

when i open it in tinymce it will display like --

```
<div><a href="www.somelink.com">Some text here</a></div>
```

when edit it -

```
<div><a href="www.somelink.com">Some text here</a>text after editing</div>
```

what i want is -

```
<div><a href="www.somelink.com">Some text here text after editing</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this. Try adding this to configuration
 valid_children:"+a[elements to allow inside a]",
valid_children:"+a[div|i|span|img|p|ul|ol|li|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h5|h6]",

[Answered for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33630082/tinymce-chenges-code-inside-anchor-tag-what-are-configration-settings)

Comment: I have already tried this solution but its not doing what i want :(.